# Is PhpUnit a trait a good practice?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, traits, xunit

In a project, we use three traits used by approximatively ten similar class (but the classes aren't working exactly in the same way).

We use trait because that's a way for communicate with 10 differents others company and all of them don't use the same input-format for receive ours datas. That's a way for us to standardize some methods according to different use cases.

---

**I want to cover a trait with some phpUnit tests because I want to test «The default use case of a class that use the trait».**

For me it's a good point to cover the default use case of a method in a trait.

If my class who use the trait are surcharging my trait-method, that's another problem, the case need to be cover too in my opinion.

---

So here is my question : **Is this is a good practice for you to cover a trait with PhpUnit?**

*sorry for my bad English…*

Comment: Yes, you should test the methods in your traits just as you do for methods in your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Testing traits is a perfectly valid use case, and PHPUnit effectively supports it with the `getMockForTrait()` method.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes

If another class overrides a trait method, you would test it in the test case for the class in question, so I don't think this would impose a problem.